# Find the parametric equation for the curve of intersection of two surfaces

Tags: calculus

I need to parametrize the curve of intersection of 2 surfaces, where the surfaces are:

$$x^2+y^2 = z$$  $$z^3 = 5x+y$$

I follow the standard step of substitution as below $$(x^2+y^2)^3 = 5x+y$$ However, this will give me a mass after I open the cube on the left side. Could anyone tell me what is the right approach for this problem?

Comment: try polar coordinates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

substitute $x = r\cos(\theta) \ and \ y = r\sin(\theta) $
which yeilds $$ r^3 = 5\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta) $$
the parametric equation of the curve is $$ \Big(\cos(\theta)\big(5\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\big)^\frac{1}{3},\sin(\theta)\big(5\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\big)^{\frac{1}{3}},\big(5\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\big)^\frac{2}{3}\Big) $$

Comment: why downvote please answer

Comment: I just see your answer today, I was not vote on this question, But I do confirm the answer same as yours as other people noticed me to try the polar coordinates, Thank you.